# Unexpected ANTLR grammar behavior

Tags: antlr, antlr3

using latest ANTLR Works 1.5, and the following grammar:

grammar TestMethod;

ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'*') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'*')*
    ;

WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) 
    ;

ws  :   (WS)*
    ;

id      :    ID
    ;

expression
    : id
    | method
    ;

method
    : identifier ws '(' ws ')'
    ;

identifier 
    :   ( id ( selector )* '.')? id
    ;

selector
    :
    '.' id
    | '[' ws expression ws ']'
    ;

I get a NoViableAltException when submitting abcd starting with expression. I don't get this error when starting with id, so since expression has id as an alternative, why does it not work ?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of times, not having an EOF (end of file) at the end of whatever it is you're starting with will cause problems. 
Try putting

> expression : (id | method) EOF;

Also, as a side note, it's a lot easier to put [a-zA-Z0-9] instead of ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|''), and [ \r\t\n] instead of ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' ), but your versions should work as well.